# Html Page: Inputed text cut off in comment box

Tags: html, comments, box

Issue: Webpage Comment section malfunction - If written text in any of the individual lines exceeds the size of the comment box it will continue to allow imputed text on that comment line resulting in lost text as it will not automatically wrap text onto the second line and onto the third comment line. Any text not typed within that goes past the size of the comment box is lost when printed.

This results in an enormous amount of lost data that I require to complete modifications to the specific needs of each customer.

Below is the webpage and comment box is on the bottom.
http://maxshepherdboltproducts.com/LW_SNP_DAT.html

I appreciate you're time and knowledge provided to help resolve this problem. - The Noob

Comment: because this is input box if you wrap text then use textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You should use texarea instead of `<input type="text">`.
 this will solve your problem.
with the help of css you can control textarea.
like `word-wrap` property.